# Symfony make:entity add property failed?

Tags: php, symfony, makefile, properties, entity

I have a problem when I want to create an entity under symfony 5.1.9 (I have the same problem under sf 4.4). I recently created a new SF project and still have the same concerns. The error message is as follows: In Validator.php line 158:
Argument 2 passed to Symfony \ Bundle \ MakerBundle \ Validator :: validateDoctrineFieldName () must be an instance of Doctrine \ Common \ Persistence \ ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine \ Bundle \ DoctrineBundle \ Registry given, called in D: \ phpProject \ API-bills \ vendor \ sy
mfony \ maker-bundle \ src \ Maker \ MakeEntity.php on line 303.

Thanks for help[image]

Comment: Should be related to https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665 The issue says that you can downgrade the doctrine bundle to 2.1.0 to fix it

Comment: Thank you very much it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the latest version is having some troubles. The easy fix for now is to modify your `composer.json` file and "downgrade" the  `doctrine/doctrine-bundle`, from version `^2.1` to `2.1.0`. After making this change, run `composer update` and everything should work.

As Florian said, referer to the [maker bundle issues](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665) to see the complete reference on this error.